# How to show authors short username with git log?

Tags: git, github, git-log

I try to get the username of the last commit of a repository using
`git log -n 1 --pretty="%an"`

Some entries in 
`git log --pretty="%an" | uniq`
shows a full username not the short login name of a commiter. I expect the git/github username.

Does there exist a way to force `git log` to show short author names and not a a maped full name?

Comment: I think you are confusing git and GitHub. Are you asking to see GitHub user names? The git repo doesn't know anything about GitHub user names.

Comment: Why does it show different author strings from same commiter?

Comment: Read about .mailmap (section "MAPPING AUTHORS" [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-shortlog.html)), that should solve your problem.

Comment: Well, I used to have to use two different names/email addresses. 1 set for work and 1 set for personal. Sometimes I wasn't careful and would end up committing something with the wrong pair. Perhaps the committers in your repo did something similar?

Comment: No I am the commiter. One commit is from my Workstation and one commit was made within the github Website . I believe there must exists another meta information I should query with git log.

Comment: @Frax I want to avoid mail mapping

Comment: Well, github needs a name and email address when it makes a commit on your behalf. If those differ from the name/email on your workstation then you'd see a difference. Does your name differ on GitHub profile from your workstation? I'll need to test this myself. I've never noticed anything strange.

Comment: What information do you write about? Commiter and author are identified by email and name, nothing else. And apperently what you want to do is mail mapping. If you are concerned about adding .mailmap to repository, you can add it to `.git/info/exclude` to make git ignore it locally.

Comment: I just checked one of my repos and I see what you are seeing for some of my co-workers. I'd research what name GitHub uses when committing on your behalf. I'm seeing my co-workers GitHub user names for some of their commits and seeing their full name for others. I'm assuming they didn't have their name filled out on GitHub when making some of those commits, so it had to use their username.

Comment: No it is the same "username". The difference is that GitHub maps my full name and uses this as author of the commit. The GitHub commit history shows what I would expect. https://github.com/s-a/beatproducer-projects/commits/master

Comment: Yes, Stephan; GitHub will do that. But git doesn't. At least not without the mail mapping dicussed by others.

Comment: @MichaelWelch So how does GitHub fetch the short author name ? I think they use git commands available in my terminal?

Comment: @StephanAhlf, I'm out of my league I guess. Here's my current understanding/assumptions. 1) GitHub can do email mapping. So it can see the email address on commits and then display the actual full name. 2) When GitHub commits on your behalf (in their UI) there are certain conditions that cause it to use your GitHub username (perhaps if you have't filled in a full user name, because it needs something). In those cases I also see it use a donotreply email address. I'm not really sure what scenario caused this. I don't know what you mean by short author name. This is not a git concept.

Comment: Like @Frax stated: git stores two identifying pieces of info: name and email. There is no "short name" concept in git. If you are seeing a short name when doing a "git log", then the committer somehow used a short name for that commit (or GitHub did). It's not really clear to me what you are seeing and what you expect/want to see.

Comment: @MichaelWelch It is like you described before. I typed my first and last name into my GitHub's profile page which GitHub UI now uses for commits. so ```git shortlog -sne``` on my workstation shows 2 different authors for same email address while https://github.com/s-a/beatproducer-projects/commits/master show only "short-name" the git user name.

Comment: I fear this mail mapping is the only way :/

Comment: Yeah, I think that is correct.

Comment: I don't know what mechanism does github internally use, but it is surely based on these two information pieces - name and email. If you use your github name or email in commit, that commit it is identified as yours (and name from profile is shown).

Comment: yes you are both right... if anybody is interested I found this API https://api.github.com/search/users?q=username@example.com to do my own mapping. bad overhead :/ ... thanks for your time!

Comment: @StephanAhlf I think the .mailmap file will work much better for you. (As it doesn't require making calls to github)

Comment: Yes it would make sense, but I need a self organized solution.